# Strang behavior with Android ListView footer click - delayed and or misordered firing

Tags: android

The click event associated with the ListView footer sometimes takes a long time to fire, especially after extensive scrolling has taken place. The regular list item clicks always fire immediately. Stranger still, when a regular item is clicked while the footer click is still waiting to process, it will fire immediately, and after it is done the footer click will immediately execute (the clicks execute in the wrong order).

Any feedback greatly appreciated.

```
private void init()
{
...

        // I attach a footer to this ListActivity instance like so...

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        mFooterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_feed_footer, null, false);

        // Add click handler to footer
        mFooterView.findViewById(R.id.feed_footer_layout).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               onFooterClick(v);
           }
        });

        getListView().addFooterView(mFooterView);

        // Register with my custom adapter
        setListAdapter(mFeedData);
}


private void onFooterClick(View footerView)
{
    // After extensive scrolling, this event will take a long time to fire (as long as 5 seconds).
    // Unless onListItemClick, in which case it will fire immediately after
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long reportSeqNo)
{
    // After extensive scrolling, this event will still fire immediately
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across a similar problem, I never did find a solution. It appears to be a bug. My workaround was to simply implement the footer as a special-case item in my ListAdapter implementation.